# Timestamp analysis in a dataframe for decide actions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have many dataframe like this:

```
               TIME    A    B    C     D     E     F  G  H  I  K
2018/07/30 10:51:14.742  540  136   20  1752  1887  2052  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:14.774  536  136   20  1879  1889  2053  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:14.805  536  136   16  2011  1888  2049  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:14.836  532  132   16  1986  1866  2028  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:14.868  524  124   16  1762  1858  2049  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:14.899  500  120   16  1806  1857  2038  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:14.930  460  116   16  1995  1856  2009  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:14.961  420  108   16  2024  1863  2064  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:14.992  392  100   16  1989  1868  2042  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.023  380   92   16  1819  1887  2040  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.055  376   84   16  1934  1868  2045  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.086  376   76   16  2034  1864  2070  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.117  376   72   16  1976  1863  2033  1  1  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.149  368   64   16  1826  1866  2057  1  0  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.180  352   60   20  1852  1878  2046  1  0  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.211  344   56   20  1863  1893  2039  1  0  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.242  328   52   20  2120  1909  2062  1  0  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.274  308   48   20  2028  1915  2105  1  0  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.305  280   44   20  1871  1911  2052  1  0  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.336  256   40   20  1927  1908  2032  1  0  0  0
2018/07/30 10:51:15.367  240   36   20  2076  1912  2031  1  0  0  0
2018/07/30 10:52:00.054  108   28   44  1869  1930  1982  0  0  1  0
2018/07/30 10:52:00.085  108   28   52  2134  1960  2094  0  0  1  0
2018/07/30 10:52:00.117  108   28   64  2084  1987  2137  0  0  1  0
2018/07/30 10:52:00.148  108   28   72  1897  1971  2112  0  0  1  0
2018/07/30 10:52:00.179  104   28   72  1977  1999  2127  0  0  1  0
2018/07/30 10:52:00.211  104   28   72  2104  1969  2081  0  0  1  0
2018/07/30 10:52:00.242  104   28   64  1904  1975  2046  0  0  1  0
```

I would like to do something like:

```
IF (df['K'] == 1) 'for MORE THAN' 1 second 
   DO something
ELSE
   DO something else
```

How can I save and remember the 0->1 transition (and viceversa), calculate the timestamps difference, and do the comparisons to decide what to do? All this in an iterative fashion?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `pandas.Series.diff` method to see the transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a flag using pandas diff, it gives you the difference in a column. Using this flag you can decide the other changes

```
df['flag']=df['K'].diff()
```